# Cannot sync branch with Github on Windows

Tags: github, synchronization, branch, antivirus

The basic problem I have is that I'm running Github on Windows and whenever I try to sync a branch, I get the error "Failed to sync this branch". When I go into Powershell and try a git push, I get the following error:

"fatal: unable to access 'http://192.168.1.50/myfolder/myproject.git/': Failed to connect to 192.168.1.50 port 80: Bad access"

I've isolated the problem to Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 since the moment I deactivate it, everything works. The problem is, due to company policies, I can't just deactivate my firewall at will, I need to call the network admin for this. So I've been working with him for the last two days, trying to add exceptions and trusted applications and the like, but Kaspersky still stubbornly blocks me no matter what we do.

Does ANYONE out there know how to tell Kaspersky to just let Github sync up through port 80!? I'm honestly at my wit's end.